# AWS - Sending 1000's of emails from Lambda / Node.js

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I have a "main" Lambda function that gets triggered by SNS. It pulls a list of recipients from the database and it needs to send each of them a message based on a template, replacing things like first name and such.

The way I have it setup is I created another Lambda function called "email-send" which is subscribed to "email-send" topic. The "main" Lambda then loops through the recipients list and publishes messages to "email-send" with a proper payload (from, to, subject, message). This might eventually need to process 1000's of emails in a single batch.

Is this a good approach to my requirements? Perhaps Lambda/SNS is not a way to go? If so, what would you recommend.

With this setup I am running into issues when my "main" function finishes running and somehow "sns.publish" does not get triggered in my loop. I assume because I am not letting it finish. But I am not sure how to fix it, being a loop.

Here is the snippet from my Lambda function:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
        // code is here to pull data into "data" array

        // process records
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var sns = new aws.SNS();
            sns.publish({
              Message: JSON.stringify({ from: data[i].from, to: data[i].to, subject: subject, body: body }),
              TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:XXXXXXXX:email-send'
            }, function(err, data) {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err.stack);
              } else {
                console.log('SNS pushed!');
              }
            });  
        }
        context.succeed("success");
};
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: You don't need SNS to invoke another Lambda function.  Just invoke it using the AWS API.

Comment: Invoking "email-send" lambda function was my initial approach. But i was running into the same issues with completion after the loop. Thoughts?

Comment: hi @enlightenedOne, Did you achieve this correctly? I also have the same problem on my desk. Can you please help (with pseudo-code/the process or steps with which you achieved this) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is doing this...

1. **Begin** calling `sns.publish()` 1000 times
2. Return (through `context.succeed()`)

You didn't wait for those 1000 calls to finish!

What your code should do is...

1. **Begin** calling `sns.publish()` 1000 times
2. When all calls to `sns.publish()` has returned, then `return`. (`context.succeed` is old so we should use `callback()` instead).

Something like this...

```
// Instantiate the client only once instead of data.length times
const sns = new aws.SNS();

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const snsCalls = []
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    snsCalls.push(sns.publish({
      Message: JSON.stringify({
        from: data[i].from,
        to: data[i].to,
        subject: subject,
        body: body
      }),
      TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:XXXXXXXX:email-send'
    }).promise();
  }

  return Promise.all(snsCalls)
    .then(() => callback(null, 'Success'))
    .catch(err => callback(err));
};
```

Comment: Thanks dashmug, but I am getting ".promise is not a function", I am missing some dependency?

Answer (score 1):

I think that a better approach is using AWS Lambda API.

That way, you don't need SNS.

**For example:**

```
var lambda = new AWS.Lambda({region: AWS_REGION});
function invokeWorkerLambda(task, callback) {
    var params = {
        FunctionName: WORKER_LAMBDA_NAME,
        InvocationType: 'Event',
        Payload: JSON.stringify({.....})
    };
    lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err, err.stack);
            callback(err);
        } else {
            callback(null, data);
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see, you don't need SNS for lambda function's invocation.

**Important:**  Another suggestion is to create an Array of invocations (`functions`) and later execute them as follow:

```
async.parallel(invocations, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err, err.stack);
        callback(err);
    }
});
```

**Take a look at this link where I got a lot of knowledge about Lambda invocation:**  https://cloudonaut.io/integrate-sqs-and-lambda-serverless-architecture-for-asynchronous-workloads/

Comment: The advantage of using SNS instead of invoking Lambda directly is that SNS *can* retry on failure.